# How to solve React native config file error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am following a tutorial on react-native app. I created a react-native.config.js file with the following lines of code

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets'],
};
```

There is a syntax error as shown in the screenshot and when I click "ctrl + ." to disable disable prettier/prettier and run `npx react-native-asset` it shows the error in the second screenshot

```
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  bracketSameLine: true,
  bracketSpacing: false,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  endOfLine: 'auto',
};
```

here is my prettierrc.js file

[image]

The code has syntax error

[image]